# icCube - How to set report component size in percentage?

Tags: iccube

I have an icCube report where I want a table component to have a dynamic size based on the screen size, but I only know how to give the components a static size in pixels.

How can I make my table component cover 50% of the report width and 100% of the report height?

Answer (score 2):

As of icCube reporting 7.10 this is not possible.

Note that the next major reporting will be more flexible regarding the "layout" support.

Comment: OK! Some kind of responsive grid layout system would be very useful. Do you have any information about when the next major release will be?